# UART RX not working on PIC16F1704

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, pic, uart, mplab

I have got the UART TX working on one pic but cannot get the UART RX working on another PIC. My plan is to have the first PIC send data to the second PIC.

My initialisation code for the first PIC TX is,

Code:

```
void configure_TX_port(){
    /*Port configurations*/
    OSCCON = 0X68;
    //Push button
    TRISC3 = 1;
    INLVLC3 = 0;
    ANSC3 = 0;
    //Led output
    TRISC2 = 0;
    //TX output
    TRISA2 = 0;   
    ANSA2 = 0;

    /*PPS setup for RA2*/
    PPSLOCK = 0x55;
    PPSLOCK = 0xAA;
    PPSLOCK = 0;
    RA2PPS = 0x14;
    PPSLOCK = 0x55;
    PPSLOCK = 0xAA;
    PPSLOCK = 1;

    /*UART configuration*/
    TXEN = 1;
    SYNC = 0;
    SPEN = 1;

    TXSTA = (0x4|0x20);
    SPBRG = (int)(4000000L/(16UL * 9600) -1);
}
```

My send data to the tx code is

Code:

```
void putch(unsigned char byte) {
    /* output one byte */
    while (!TXIF) /* set when register is empty */

    TXREG = byte;
}
```

My initialisation code for the second PIC RX is,

```
void configure_RX_port(){
    /*Port configurations*/
    OSCCON = 0X68;
    //Led output
    TRISC3 = 0;
    //RX input
    TRISC5 = 1;
    ANSC5 = 0;

    /*UART configuration*/
    CREN = 1;
    SYNC = 0;
    SPEN = 1;
    TXSTA = (0x4|0x20);
    RCSTA = 0x90;
    SPBRG = (int)(4000000L/(16UL * 9600) -1);
}
```

My receive data code is,

```
unsigned char getch(void) {
    /* retrieve one byte */
    unsigned char ret;
    while (!RCIF) {  /* set when register is not empty */
    }
    ret = RCREG;
    return ret;
}
```

When I debug the code the getch function gets blocked waiting on a character but my other PIC is sending data. On this PIC RC5 is a designated RX pin so I dont think I have to do any pps configuration.

Rahul

Comment: Did you enable interrupts? If could include more details, such as initialization and etc anyone would get more understanding.

Comment: interrupts are not required in this case to read the RCIF and TXIF registers, they are set regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TX1STA = 0b00100100; This enablex TX (TXEN=1) and high baud rate (BRGH = 1)

RC1STA = 0b10000000; This enable the serial port (SPEN = 1)
```

The only important missing part is your Clock setting and the baudrate you want to have.

I saw 4000000 in the formula, means 4MHz, and /9600, so assume 9600BDS).

Result = 0x25.

```
SPBRGL = 0x25; 

SPBRGH = 0;
```

This way, your TX should work. Your tx function is good.

Be sure to configure RX and TX pins as DIGITAL by disabling ANSELA, ANSELB and ANSELC.
Your PIC also use PPS, so be sure to configure it the right way.

***********EDITED POST, RECEIVE CONDITION**************

The only difference here to get a working receiver is to enable the continuous receiver 
bit, CREN.

`RC1STA = 0b10010000; //Enable serial port(SPEN) and continuous receive(CREN)`.

**Be sure to set RX pin (RC5 in your case) as an INPUT (TRISC5 = 1)** so that it can read any entering data. You should also consider doing an interrupt routine instead of polling the receiver flag bit. That way you're sure not to skip any entering data.

Comment: Please see my modified code, I am not sure if I am using the PPS uart properly, I unlock pps, set RA2PPS to be a tx port and then lock pps. I have also set all the relevant pins to digital.

Comment: The only difference here to get a working receiver is to enable the continuous receiver bit, CREN.

RC1STA = 0b10010000; //Enable serial port(SPEN) and continuous receive(CREN). 

Be sure to set RX pin (RC5 in your case) as an INPUT (TRISC5 = 1) so that it can read any entering data.
You should also consider doing an interrupt routine instead of polling the receiver flag bit. That way you're sure not to skip any entering data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your answer is the same as what I have in my edited code. I was wondering if the TXSTA and RCSTA registers need to be set (to set the bits) or can for example the CREN value be set explicitly?

Comment: Usually, setting registers will be easier for you, as you won't skip any particular bit (ex TXEN in TXSTA), I've always done it this way and most of the time it's easier to debug right after as you see the value you have written to the register and you can rely on the datasheet to see if this is the right value for your desired operations. In your uart reception routine, poll a bit with an LED connected to that port, to see if there's any activity out there.

You are using 2 same pics? Same BaudRate? Maybe you have an interrupt enabled and it get's stuck in there?

Answer (score 0):

You look to be using asynchronous mode with `SYNC = 0`, but do not set `TXEN = 1`.

Setting `CREN = 1` only overrides `TXEN` in synchronous mode. Try setting `TXEN = 1`.

Comment: I am using SYNC = 0 for asynchronous mode.

Comment: I have got the TX part working with the above code, please see the edit, I am now having issues with the RX code on a separate PIC. The idea is the first PIC will send data to the second PIC. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default at reset all pins on PIC16F1704 are set as analog.
So clear coresponding bits of RX and TX pins in registers ANSELA, ANSELB and ANSELC to set tham as digital.

Comment: I have set the relevant pins to digital, problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line, TXSTA = (0x4|0x20); to the receiver PIC code and it works now. There is no need for

```
CREN = 1;
SYNC = 0;
SPEN = 1;
```

as its setting the same bits.